# How to covert a large JSON file into XML?

Tags: json, xml

I have a large JSON file, its size is 5.09 GB. I want to convert it to an XML file. I tried online converters but the file is too large for them. Does anyone know how to to do that?

Comment: Even if you proceed manually, you're going to run out of memory.

Comment: Streaming JSON readers and XML writers will be the solution here, but as you've specified no details about your situation, that's the most specific advice I can give.

Comment: Note that json takes less space than xml. So you are looking at almost double the size of the original file after conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to process XML as well as JSON files is to load these files completely into memory. Then you have a so called DOM which allows you various kinds of data processing. But neither XML nor JSON are really designed for storing that much data you have here. To my experience you typically will run into memory problems as soon as you exceed a 200 MByte limit. This is because DOMs are created that are composed from individual objects. This approach results in a huge memory overhead that far exceeds the amount of data you want to process.

The only way for you to process files like that is basically to take a stream approach. The basic idea: Instead of parsing the whole file and loading it into memory you parse and process the file "on the fly". As data is read it is parsed and events are triggered on which your software can react and perform some actions as needed. (For details on that have a look at the SAX API in order to understand this concept in more detail.)

As you stated you are processing JSON, not XML. Stream APIs for JSON should be available in the wild as wel. Anyway you could implement one fairly easily yourself: JSON is a pretty simple data format.

Nevertheless such an approach is not optimal: Typically such a concept will result in very slow data processing because of millions of method invocations involved: For every item encountered you typically need to call a method in order to perform some data processing task. This together with additional checks about what kind of information you currently have encountered in the stream will slow down data processing pretty much.

You really should consider to use a different kind of approach. First split your file into many small ones, then perform processing on them. This approach might not seem to be very elegant, but it helps to keep your task much simpler. This way you gain a main advantage: It will be much easier for you to debug your software. Unfortunately you are not very specific about your problem, so I can only guess, but large files typically imply that the data model is pretty complex. Therefor you will probably be much better off by having many small files instead of a single huge one. And later it allows you to dig into individual aspects of your data and the data processing process as needed. You will probably fail getting any detailed insights into that while having a single large file of 5 GByte to process. On errors you will have trouble to identify which part of the huge file is causing the problem.

As I already stated you unfortunately are very unspecific about your problem. Sorry, but because of having no more details about your problem (and your data in particular) I can only give you these general recommendations about data processing. I do not know any details about your data, so I can not give you any recommendation about which approach will work best in your case.